# ¿Como se puede subir archivos pesados por partes en javascript y PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Mi pregunta (como aparece en el título) ¿Como se puede subir archivos pesados por partes en javascript y PHP?.

Lo que quiero es, cuando un archivo supere los 10MB se particiones y se suban al servidor a PHP. Para subir archivos pesados más que todo...

Comment: Hola CMNetwork, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Déjame comentarte que mas que para buscar información o pedir recomendaciones, esta comunidad se enfoca en contestar preguntas específicas, puntuales o concretas. Por eso mismo, los temas como el que planteas resultan muy amplios para el enfoque del sitio y son, generalmente, cerradas con prontitud. Te invito a que conozcas como funciona esta comunidad visitando el [tour]. Si tienes una pregunta concreta, edita esta publicación siguiendo la guía [mcve].

Comment: Abres el achivo con File API en javascript, lo partes, evias las partes con ajax, con parametros en el queryString o en Cabeceras HTTP indicas que parte estas enviando, en php dedicas una ruta (un endpoint) para recibir las partes, sabes que parte es por parametros antes enviados, a medida que recibes cada parte reconstruyes el archivo grabando ese _pedazo_ en el sitio correcto de un file previamente creado con el tamaño declarado del file. Ten muy en cuenta que debes authenticar cada pedazo, posiblemente usando un token y CORS (hay otras formas).

Comment: Seria recomendable utilizar un hash md5 o similar para comprobar que el file no este corrupto o que faltan partes y quiza se me escapa algo mas. Como ves, es bastante trabajo. Pero ya hay soluciones hechas, ej: https://github.com/sthielen/BigUpload

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme. No respondí antes porque soy nuevo aquí y no se mucho de las funciones de esta web.

Yo actualmente subo archivos vía JS, pero mi objetivo final es que así como hace está web (http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/bufferWhenNeeded.html) para descargar el vídeo por parte, tambien hacerlo con subida.

La web que me mostraste https://github.com/sthielen/BigUpload, es interesante pero ya yo tengo un sistema hecho y en el caso tengo que implementarlo haber que tal... ;)